# user and role authorization in swagger api express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

guys

on my exisiting api i already have user authhication using Bearer security. Using http header api_key and later tokens.

My problem seems to be i have diffefrent end point that are only need to be consumed based on roles.

For example to post a new user :

```
POST user should only be authenticated to user with admin role.
```

I have looked at the [swagger spec here](http://swagger.io) but nothing i could find on thier docuemation and google as well.

Please could give me some brain stroming idea ? below is my access verifaction code in **nodejs and express.**

```
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

  app.use(middleware.swaggerSecurity({
    Bearer: function(req,def,apiKey,next){
        apiKey= apiKey.slice(7)
        debug("token check",def,apiKey)
        var ok=checkToken(apiKey)
        if(ok) {
          req.user=ok
          debug('Token is ok')
          return next()
        }
        debug("Invalid token",apiKey)
        var err=Error("Invalid token")
        err.statusCode=403
        next(err)
    }
  }));
```

Comment: Were you able to find documentation on this, or solve this? I am stuck here myself, and it appears so cumbersome to add security check to every method in every service my API exposes. I am surprised no one at swagger has addressed this.

Comment: i have done it !!!

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, the solution is still homebrewing. Swagger does not, save through oAuth scopes or using a "hacky" api-key security definition (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222161/3736937), have a built in RBAC mechanism.

Fortunately, we can create some pretty basic middleware to handle the problem because swagger does allow us to add x-swagger-* members to the swagger definition.

So here's what I did:

1. Add x-swagger-roles to each endpoint that requires RBAC (Role-based Access Control)

   ```
   paths:
     "/":
       x-swagger-router-controller: getStatus
       get:
         operationId: getStatus
         x-swagger-roles:
           - admin
         tags:
           - "users"
         summary: "Returns message: 'working'"
         description: "default endpoint for testing"
         responses:
           $ref: "#/definitions/AnyResponse"
   ```
2. Place middleware *before* swagger-node-runner is registered with the application. In our case we're using expressjs, so the connect middleware is used.

   ```
   var findOne = function (haystack, arr) {
       return arr.some(function (v) {
           return haystack.indexOf(v) >= 0;
       });
   };

   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     var operation = runner.getOperation(req);
     if(operation && operation.definition) {
       var definition = operation.definition;
       var requiredRoles = definition['x-swagger-roles'];

       // if the endpoint has no required roles then go to the next route
       if(!requiredRoles) return next();

       // get the users roles
       var userRoles = req.session.roles; // this may differ for you

       // if any roles match then go to the next route
       if(findOne(userRoles, requiredRoles)) return next();

       // if no roles match then assert that this endpoint is forbidden
       else return res.sendStatus(403);
     }
     next();
   })

   // it's important to register the middleware after the role check
   runner.expressMiddleware().register(app);
   ```

Notes:

1. This code has not been tested in production, and should be reviewed by a security professional.
2. x-swagger-roles will not appear in your swagger-ui without altering it, which is beyond the scope of this answer.