# Swagger specific security for a path

Tags: node.js, api, documentation, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a Node.js API in which I want to add swagger documentation. Clients authorize via JWT, so I added this to security:

```
securityDefinitions:
  UserSecurity:
    type: apiKey
    description: User is logged in
    in: header
    name: Authorization
```

Than I can add this to different paths to tell the client, to do this you need to be logged in.

```
/user/{userId}
  get:
    security:
      - UserSecurity: []
```

But how do I add more specific security constrains? Like, the user can only edit the profile if logged as that user. Or a user can edit a comment if he has superadmin status OR if he is admin for the board the comment is posted at OR is logged as the user that created this comment.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to define role/permission security in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40162062/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to add 'roles' to swagger documentation.

What I did, is that I'm adding a custom section to the swagger file `x-scope`:

```
get:
    operationId: getToken
    x-scope:
      - merchant
    security:
      - token: []
```

Then in the code I check the role of the user against the one provided in the path:

```
authorize: (req, def, token, callback) => {
  let scopes = req.swagger.operation["x-scope"];
  //scopes will contain ["merchant"] array

  return verifyUserAndRoles(token, scopes);
}
```

Comment: Works fine like this, thanks. In case there are very specific security requirements I tried to define my scopes in a better way. If not possible, I added these requirements into the the 401 response as description.

Comment: Yep, it's quite hard to do really specific requirements in swagger definition file